# VB.net ContextMenu is not Updating

Tags: vb.net, contextmenu, updating

I have a project I converted from VS 2008 to VS 2015 and I am having an issue with the context menu's items not updating their text when the program runs.  For instance, I have an item named "Quick Dig" and I need to change it to "Quick Hitch".  It shows up fine on the context menu and in the properties of the context menu, but when I run the program it still shows "Quick Dig".  Similarly, when I try and add items to the context menu, the new items do not show up either.  They show up fine in the context menu and in the properties, but again, when I run the program, it doesn't have them included.

How can I get the context menu to update the new text and also include the additions I am making?  Nothing I have tried has helped...

Comment: Is this the only context menu present in your design? Are you sure that you are calling the correct one?

Comment: Yes, the menu pops up fine.  The issue is the changes I make are not updating, and neither are the additions I make to it.  It shows the original one no matter what I do.  All of the changes are showing when I look at the properties and the items, but when I run it, the old menu still shows up without the changes I make carrying over or the new items I put in there...its almost like it has a copy of the context menu saved somewhere and it is using that version instead of the updated version

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow, This is just a message I send to new members to help things along a bit. The learning curve for a new user isn't steep as such, but finding out how to use stack isn't always obvious. Please do take a few minutes and have a look here [ask] and it's also important to look here .. [mcve].. Also, if an answer is valid for you, click on the tick to the left of the answer so that the question is marked as answered and this makes sure that the person who posted it gets reputation. Cheers.